# Mongodb aggregation performance with indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a structure similar to this.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d7cd63dc2c91e740afcdb"),
        "dateJoined": ISODate("2014-12-28T16:37:17.984Z"),
        "dateActivatedMonth": 15, 
        "enrollments" : [
            { "month":-10, "enrolled":'00'},
            { "month":-9, "enrolled":'00'},
            { "month":-8, "enrolled":'01'},
            //other months
            { "month":8, "enrolled":'11'},
            { "month":9, "enrolled":'11'},
            { "month":10, "enrolled":'00'}
        ]
    }
```

dateActivatedMonth is number of months from dateJoined.

month in enrollments sub document is a relative month from dateJoined.

I am using Mongodb aggregation framework to process queries like "all enrollments with enrolled as '01' and 'enrolled month is 10 months before activation and 25 months after activation' ".

In my aggregation, first I am applying all possible filters in the $match pipeline and the applying condition on "month" in the $project pipeline.

```
db.getCollection("enrollments").aggregate(
    { $match:{ //initial conditions }},
    { $project: {
          //Here i will apply month filter by considering the number of month before and after.
       }
    }
    //other pipeline operations
)
```

All the filters that I am applying in my condition are optional. So in some cases $match will not filter anything. The only condition that is guaranteed to be there is the one on "month" in the "enrollments" sub document.

This query is slow. Takes about 6-7 seconds. (data is also huge). I am looking for ways to improve this. First thing I am looking at is to create indexes.

Now my questions are:

1. Can $project use indexes? I tried creating index on month" but I don't see anything about index usage in the queryPlanner with explain()
2. I would like to move the "month" condition to $match, So that it uses the index. How can I use a field value in $match? something like this:

   ```
   db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
   {
       $match:{
           dateActivatedMonth: {$exists: true}
           //,'enrollment.month': dateActivatedMonth  -- not working
           //,'enrollment.month': '$dateActivatedMonth' -- not working
       }
   }])
   ```

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Have you read [the docs on the topic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance)?

Comment: Yes, I did. My understanding was $project cannot use indexes. This is the reason for question #2. But I am not sure if I am missing something. so let me know if have any advise.

Comment: This question is hard to answer because it's written like you're trying to tweak something that's working to use an index but you don't show the working query.